# Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64

Tags: linux, terminal

I try to run `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
But i get an error.

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64
E: Couldnt find any package by glob 'linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64
E: Couldnt find any package by regex'linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64
```

So here is the thing, i change source.list with (https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories) these repositories(the links). 
I think my version of kali is doesnt match with the links.
When i write `apt-cache search linux-headers` , my headers seems as linux-headers-4.16.0-kali2-all...

So is there any suggestion? How can i solve this problem ? Or is there any link for the 4.16.0 version?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem with kali, and got it working by updating linux-image and linux-headers packages:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
apt-cache search linux-image
```

then search **latest** linux-image and linux-source packages with the same version. In my case output was

```
linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.17.0-kali1-amd64
linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-cloud-amd64 - Header files for Linux 4.17.0-kali1-cloud-amd64
linux-image-4.17.0-kali1-amd64 - Linux 4.17 for 64-bit PCs
linux-image-4.17.0-kali1-amd64-dbg - Debug symbols for linux-image-4.17.0-kali1-amd64
...
```

so then I just installed latest versions:

```
apt-get install linux-headers-4.17.0-kali1-amd64 linux-image-4.17.0-kali1-amd64 -y
reboot
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to upgrade to the latest kali version (4.17.0) by running this command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-4.17.0-kali3-amd64
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all try to change the line

> linux-headers-4.15.0-kali2-amd64

to

> linux-headers-4.15.0-kali-amd64

Because there are no kali2 thing at all.

Also what you can do is to run

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

It will show all available headers.

Comment: E: ... (These are errors ?) kali send me those lines as kali2? How can i change these error kali2 to kali ?    Also i run apt-cache search linux-headers . The results are linux-headers-4.16.0-kali2-all ... (those all of them 4.16.0) @delmys-asteroraena

Comment: Then install those headers then. sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.16.0-kali2-all. My fault on part with kali2 sorry.

Comment: There is no link for 4.16.0-kali2-all ( the last version of these links are 4.15.0)